# XOR a byte array in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, xor

I have made the following function, which will XOR a message with a key by using cycle() to avoid length counting and works well. I need to do the same thing with C-Style byte arrays. Any help appreciated. My string XOR function:

```
from itertools import cycle, izip

def xor(message, key):
    toret = ''
    for c, k in izip(message, cycle(key)):
        toret += chr(ord(c) ^ ord(k))
    return toret

print xor("test", "234556346")
```

Comment: Hint: A `bytearray` is internally a sequence of integers.

Comment: What do you mean by "C-style byte array"?

Comment: @interjay \xbf\x88\xa9\x98 something like that

Comment: Then run your function with `"\xbf\x88\xa9\x98"` as an input.

Comment: @interjay but that way it will not be treated as a byte array but as a string instead, right?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean by "byte array". A string in Python 2.7 is an array of bytes.